# Listar Códigos de Um Determinado Fornecedor no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Eu tenho uma Tabela de Produtos com Código e Fornecedor.

Gostaria de saber como posso na tabela de fornecedores listar todos os códigos de um fornecedor específico.

Consigo fazer isso só através de fórmulas no Excel?

Exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boas @lukkicode,

veja se esta solução serve para o que pretendes.

### Tabela Dinâmica

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom. Não sabia que existia essa opção.
Mas será que tem como fazer de forma horizontal e por fórmula?
(vou inserir mais dados do fornecedor depois)

Comment: Através de formula não estou a conseguir chegar ao resultado que pretendes mas pode ser que alguem consiga. Mesmo que insiras mais dados do fornecedor basta actualizar a origem dos dados.

Comment: Vou utilizar da forma que você falou. Valeu R.Galamba.